# C# Maui Content of a grid within a collectionview doesn't shrink to original (or smaller) size when window shrinks

Tags: c#, maui-community-toolkit

In picture 1 I start off with a very small window and both columns divide the screen width as specified in the xaml (ColumnDefinitions="*,150").
In picture 2 the first column expands to its maximum allowed size when enlarging the window.
Lastly when the window is shrunk again the content is overrun because the first column doesn't shrink back.

[Change in width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LItAY.png)

```
    <Grid x:Name="DownloadsMenu"
          Padding="10"
          RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,*">
        <Button ... />
        <Label ... />
        <Line ... />
        <CollectionView x:Name="DataView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}"
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        MaximumWidthRequest="800">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Downld__">
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,150"
                          Padding="5">
                        <Frame Padding="10,5,10,5">
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                                            <Binding Path="Event___" />
                                            <Binding Path="Photog__" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Label.Text>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Text="{Binding Size____, Converter={StaticResource BytesToReadable}}" />
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Button Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
                                Text="{Binding Status__, Converter={StaticResource EnumToDescription}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <ActivityIndicator ... />
    </Grid>
```

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.8.0 Preview 1.0

What can be done to make the inner VerticalStackLayout shrink when the window shrinks ?

I've tried to encapsulate the VerticalStackLayout in another element (grid, layout, frame)

Comment: If you are talking about WPF you may want to Tag the Question accordingly. And presumably the CollectionView Tag you used is for a different kind of control in a different technology. In case remove that one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and have found a workaround.

In my viewmodel I have an ObservableCollection Projects which is displayed using a CollectionView on my ContentPage.
Then I have the following method:

```
public async Task ReloadProjects()
{
    var temp = Projects.ToList();
    Projects.Clear();
    await Task.Delay(1);
    foreach (var project in temp)
    {
        Projects.Add(project);
    }
}
```

This method gets called from the code-behind of my ContentPage each time the page is resized:

```
private async void OnPageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await viewModel.ReloadProjects();
}
```

This asynchronous reloading of my Projects correctly rescales the width of my grid columns. I'm wondering if there's a better fix for this issue though and would love to hear if you found something else.

Comment: I'm sorry but reloading wouldn't work for me. Moved on to Avalonia in the meantime.